# R: Line Plot for each Signal (Elements) in a List as PDF

Tags: r, list, pdf, plot, signals

I am currently working with respiration data (N = 97 signals), which are all stored in one list. Each element in the list represents one signal.

Example List Structure:

```
S1 = rep(1:10000, 1)
S2 = rep(1:15000, 1.5)
S3 = rep(1:25000, 0.5)

List1 = list(S1, S2, S3)
```

What I need for visual inpsection of the data is a function that creates a simple line graph for each respiration signal and stores the result in one big PDF file. Ideally the name of each element of the list becomes the title of the corresponding graph and I only have 1-3 graphs per page.

Unfortunately, I did not even come close to a working solution. I would appreciate any help or tips!

Answer (score 0):

```
pfad.plot <- "/Users/.../" #directory where you want the pdf to be safed

pdf(file = paste0(pfad.plot, "test.pdf"),
    width = 12, height = 9, onefile = TRUE, family = "Helvetica",
    fonts = NULL, version = "1.2",
    pointsize=14) #open line to pdf

par(mfrow = c(3,1))
#par sets all different graphical parameters 
#mfrow gives the number of colums, number of rows

plot(List1[[1]]) #S1 from list
plot(S2) #S2 directly

dev.off() #important to close the open line to the pdf
```